# Creating Composite Primary Key in Child Class (JPA)

Tags: java, jpa

Suppose I have the following situation between a parent class and child class:

```
Class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column(name="product")
    Long product;

    //more fields.
}

Class Child extends Parent {
    @Column(name="type")
    String productType;

    @Column(name="version")
    int version;

    //more fields.
}
```

Is it possible to to have a composite primary key in the Child class even though the Child Class extends the Parent which already has a primary key?

Comment: probably depends on the inheritance strategy, basically for your usecase you need at least `table per class` strategy because one table can't have two primary keys, I don't know what do you need besides this, have you tried `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` and then setting different `@Id` in children(caution : table per class may not be best for efficiency)

Comment: If you describe your real goal of this like what is `Parent` and `Child` and why do you need for child to have different primary key maybe we can guide you into a better solution

Comment: @niceman thank you for your very prompt response. I have not tried the strategy `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`. I'll look into that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.  In JPA, you can not redefine primary keys.  If your parent class has an @ID annotation, no subclass would allow @ID annotations regardless of inheritance strategy.

The longer answer is that if you need to do something like this, you should re-think your object mapping and your inheritance strategy.  If you have a parent that already has a uniquely identifiable set of fields, why are you looking to have a child that breaks this convention?  And even if you succeed, is this a safe thing for you to do in terms of architecture and code clarity?

Comment: thank you for your prompt response. I will rethink the object mapping and inheritance strategy.